# Web application translation not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, cross-browser, translation

I have a web application which supports English and Danish language. The user is able to change the language from the settings in the application. The language setting is stored in a database as either a '1' or a '2' for English and Danish respectively. A text file containing all the necessary translations acts as a dictionary and if Danish is chosen, all words and phrases are translated according to that dictionary.
In IE this works perfectly, but in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox, only some text is translated properly while the rest is translated according to the language setting in the browser.
Here is my controller function (vb.net), which gets the user's language from the database:

```
Public Function GetCurrentUserLanguageContent() As ActionResult

    Dim language As Integer = sInt(GetSingleValue("SELECT language_id FROM Users WHERE user_id =" & CurrentUser.Userid))

    Dim langCode As String

    If language = 2 Then
        langCode = "da-DK"
    Else
        langCode = "en-GB"
    End If

    Dim languageSet = New With {.LangCode = langCode, .Translations = My.Resources.daDKLang}
    Return languageSet

End Function
```

My script (JavaScript (technically typescript) and jQuery) looks like this:

```
interface langDefinition {
LangCode: string;
Translations: string; 
}

class translatedLang {  
dictionary = new Array<string>();
defaultLangauge = "en-GB";
currentLanguage: string;
isDefaultLanguage: boolean;

constructor() {

    try { 
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "...",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false, 
            cache: false,
            success: function (langDef: langDefinition) {
                self.currentLanguage = langDef.LangCode;
                self.isDefaultLanguage = self.currentLanguage == self.defaultLangauge;
                self.setupDictionary(langDef.Translations); 
                var rnotwhite = /\S/; 
                $('body *').contents().filter(function () {
                    return this.nodeType === 3 && rnotwhite.test($(this).text());
                }).text(function (i, text) {
                        this.replaceWholeText(self.translate(text));
                        //this.nodeValue = text + ' replaced';     // this works, in that it adds 'replaced' to the missing translations
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
    catch (ex) {
        this.isDefaultLanguage = true;
    }
}

private setupDictionary(translations: string): void {
    translations.split(/\r\n/g).forEach((value: string) => {
        var keyValuePair: string[] = value.split(",");
        this.dictionary[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
    });
}

public translateNewlineString(translationString: string): string {
    return translationString
           .split(/\r\n/g)
           .map((l) => {
                return this.translate(l);
            })
           .join(" ");
}

public translate(translationString: string): string {
    if (this.isDefaultLanguage) {
        return translationString;
    }
    else {
        if (this.dictionary.hasOwnProperty(translationString)) {
            return this.dictionary[translationString];
        }
        else {
            return translationString;
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can tell from the setupDictionary function, the dictionary file is formatted like so:
`something in english,something in danish
 something else in english, something else in danish`

Note that if I change `this.replaceWholeText(self.translate(text));` to `this.nodeValue = text + ' replaced';` in the AJAX call, the text that should be tranlated is changed to include 'replaced' - meaning it actually changed the right text...

And again; this all works fine in IE, but some browsers like Chrome for instance, seems to override my translations in some cases.
Is there any way to fix that, or do I need to do something completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself; I just had to change `this.replaceWholeText(self.translate(text));` to `this.nodeValue = self.translate(text);`, so the AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "...",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false, 
        cache: false,
        success: function (langDef: langDefinition) {
            self.currentLanguage = langDef.LangCode;
            self.isDefaultLanguage = self.currentLanguage == self.defaultLangauge;
            self.setupDictionary(langDef.Translations); 
            var rnotwhite = /\S/; 
            $('body *').contents().filter(function () {
                return this.nodeType === 3 && rnotwhite.test($(this).text());
            }).text(function (i, text) {
                this.nodeValue = self.translate(text);
            });
        }
    });
```